# In JS, how do I determine if a string is contained within another string?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In Javascript, how do I determine if some specific HTML is contained within a larger hunk of HTML?

I tried regex:

```
var htmlstr;
var reg = /<b class="fl_r">Example</b>/.test(htmlstr);
```

but it doesn't work! Console outputs "missing /". Please, help me fix this.

Comment: Please no.... [NOOOOOOOooooooooo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: So, is there any other way to see if this string contains that substring??

Comment: +1 to @rockintheixstring for first to reference that post

Comment: are you trying to get "Example" from within an element with a class of `fl_r`?

Comment: @rockinthesixstring, there may be more than one "Example"  on the page. i need exactly this "Example" -surrounded with <b class="fl_r"> and </b>

Comment: @rockinthesixstring, another question - in case of xhtml, in general, should i parse it as html or as xml??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is a bit of an overkill here.  You can just use indexOf like this and not have to worry about escaping things in the string:

```
var htmlstr1 = 'foo';
var htmlstr2 = 'some stuff <b class="fl_r">Example</b> more stuff';

if (htmlstr1.indexOf('<b class="fl_r">Example</b>') != -1) {
    alert("found match in htmlstr1");
}

if (htmlstr2.indexOf('<b class="fl_r">Example</b>') != -1) {
    alert("found match in htmlstr2");
}
```

jsFiddle to play with it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/86Kny/

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `/` character.

Try:

```
var htmlstr = '<b class="fl_r">Example</b>';
var reg =  /<b class="fl_r">Example<\/b>/.test(htmlstr);
```

Example @ http://jsfiddle.net/7cuKe/2/

Comment: it worked the first time. but after i assigned <b class="fl_r">Example</b> to htmlstr, it doesnt work anymore! (i anticipated 'true') :(

Comment: @Dr: Updated the post. Pls check